# C# dictionary with a float value?

Tags: c#, asp.net, generics, dictionary

I have values that have decimals that I would like to store in a dictionary for easy access. However in C# it only allows a string and an int. Is there another way I can achieve similar results?

This is my code:

```
   littledictionary.Add("price", (float)0.0);
   littledictionary["price"] = (float)SQLreader["price"];
```

Comment: It will only allow a `string` and an `int` if you've created a `Dictionary<string,int>`.

Comment: Please post the declaration of the Dictionary. You can use `float` as Key and/or as Value. (use the _edit_ link).

Comment: Also, what is the SQL-type of the price column?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What do you mean?  You can use a float-based dictionary:

```
var littledictionary = new Dictionary<string,float>();
littledictionary.Add("price", (float)0.0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Or alternatively you can use List:

```
List<Decimal> list1 = new List<decimal>();
```

You can see how to use lists here: http://www.dotnetperls.com/list

Hope this helps.